# How to use ngrx signalStore in facade pattern?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, signals, ngrx

In angular I want use ngrx new signalStore to get locations of arms and save in state, problem is I don't know how to wait response of locations and after set in map with markers want to replace Service with LOCATION_STORE

```
export const LOCATION_STORE = signalStore(
  { providedIn: "root" },
  withState(() => inject(LOCATION_STORE_INITIAL_STATE)),
  withMethods((store, atmService: AtmsService = inject(AtmsService)) => ({
    fetchLocations: rxMethod<void>(pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => patchState(store, { loading: true })),
      mergeMap(() => atmService.getBranchesAndAtms().pipe(
        tapResponse({
          next: (locations: Array<LocationModel>) => {
            const branches: Array<LocationModel> = locations.filter((res: LocationModel) => res.isBranch);
            const atms: Array<LocationModel> = locations.filter((res: LocationModel) => !res.isBranch);
            return patchState(store, { atms, branches })
          },
          error: (errorCode: string) => patchState(store, { error: errorCode }),
          finalize: () => patchState(store, { loading: false })
        })
      ))
    )),
  }))
)

# I use google map library 

 initiateMap(mapContainer: HTMLElement) {
    return forkJoin([ this.getGoogleMap(mapContainer), this._atmService.getBranchesAndAtms() ]).pipe(
      tap(([ googleMap, locations ]): void => {
        const markers: Array<google.maps.Marker> = this.addMarkers(locations);
        this.addMarkerClusterer(googleMap, markers);
      })
    )
  }
```